# Is there a way to create a graph that has iterated pairs of consecutive items in its own x-axis and values of the pairs in its own y-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to iterate over all pairs of consecutive items in the list called as ObjectIDs, then I want to plot and demonstrate a 2D graph that shows each slop value between the two specific nodes/points from the list called Slops.

```
meterBetweenTwoPoints = 5
currentPointDateTimes = []
objectHeights = []
objectIDs = []
objectsIDsForGraphNodes = []
slopeValues = []

..

for x in range(0, len(objectHeights)): 
    objectsIDsForGraphNodes.append(objectIDs[sortedIndexLibrarycurrentPointDateTimes[x]])

print(objectsIDsForGraphNodes)

>> [1480642, 1504454, 1504455, 1504456, 1504457, 1504458]

for x in range(0, len(objectHeights)-1):
    pointXHeight = objectHeights[sortedIndexLibrarycurrentPointDateTimes[x]]
    pointYHeight = objectHeights[sortedIndexLibrarycurrentPointDateTimes[x+1]]
    currentSlopeValue = ((pointYHeight - pointXHeight) / meterBetweenTwoPoints) * 100
    slopeValues.append(currentSlopeValue)

print(slopeValues)

>> [-14.6541400000001, -4.927820000000054, -2.8426600000000235, -2.2563800000000356, -1.0200999999997862]
```

Therefore, this means that I have 6 different nodes and 5 different slope values.

As you can see, the size of lists is not equal but I can assign an extra "zero" to the list called slopeValues. I can convert the list into data frames but still couldn't manage to make it.

My environment cannot support libs like "plotly".

I prepared a visualization to make my request/demand clear:

[image]

This graph represents the desired output. I tried multiple solutions by using matplotlib, seaborn, and pandas but I couldn't manage to execute an output.

In addition to this, is there any better visualization to show the inclination/slope values between to specific points(for roads)?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = [1480642, 1504454, 1504455, 1504456, 1504457, 1504458]
Y = [-14.6541400000001, -4.927820000000054, -2.8426600000000235, -2.2563800000000356, -1.0200999999997862]
#Custom X tick text
X_ticks = ['['+ str(X[i]) + '-' + str(X[i+1]) +']' for i in range(0,len(X)-1)]

# add 0 to make list size equal
X_ticks.insert(0, 0)
Y.insert(0,0)

#Draw Plot
plt.figure(1, figsize = (12,6))
plt.suptitle('Slope Plot')
ax = plt.gca()
x_axis = range(0,len(X_ticks))

ax.set_xlim([0, len(X_ticks)])
ax.set_ylim([0, min(Y) - 2 ])

# Draw horizontal lines
for v in Y:
  plt.axhline(y=v, color='g', linestyle='--')

plt.xticks(x_axis, X_ticks)
plt.yticks(Y)
plt.plot(x_axis, Y, 'ro--')
```

Here is the plot :-
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working like charm and desired. I do not know why you are downvoted but your answer is what I really need, and it is unfair to see that. Do you mind if I ask how to fill above of the graph's red line to demonstrate it easier to read?

Comment: @sukruburakcetin Great to know it worked for you. Even I was wondering about 'downvote' . I thought you might have done it :) . 
Pardon me , I did not understand completely `how to fill above of the graph's red line` . Do you mean to have a solid line or area fill above red line.

Comment: Actually, I used your solution immediately after I saw it, but I was trying to make it more complex and advanced so I just waited to see that if I have more questions before closing the topic and marking your answer as the best one. I tried to upvote you but I needed 15 points to reach that position since it is only 13 for now. 

Oh, sorry for using the opposite direction. I wanted below of the red line. Here I provide visual clarification: [link]https://imgur.com/a/5x9ct38

Comment: My last question is if I use more points, I mean more than ~50, the graph labeling becomes not easier o read. Is there a way to solve it? Like this one, [link]https://i.imgur.com/rMoRsId.png Google Earth minimizes x-axis points and optimizes its axis labeling capacity to make it easier to read. For a few points, it shows 2.5 meters between the nodes but if you pick too many points it shows only every 100 or 200 meters. What I want is to preserve the curve while showing/labeling it in a wide range. This is what I mean: [link]https://i.imgur.com/W0wcAAy.png

Comment: I'm so sorry for the question overload. I really appreciate your work and never wanted to let you think that you are downvoted.

Last but not least, this is what I got when I try to initiate and iterate 296 points.
[link]https://imgur.com/a/BLYK8yQ

As you can see, cannot see numbers since the graph is not interactive, and it becomes too complex. I just want to narrow the range(like mimicking the output from a wider range to a closer range).  @aberry